# Get values of enum as list of strings

Tags: java, enums

I have the following enum and want to convert it to a list of its string values:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum danger{

    Danger("DGR"),
    Normal("NOR");


    /**
     * The value.
     */
    private final String value;
}
```

**Desired Output:** List of "DGR" and "NOR"

My current solution looks like:

```
List<String> dangerlist = Stream.of(DangerousShipment.values())
                .map(Enum::name)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The problem is, I can only select the name of the enum and not the actual value.

Comment: replace the map with `DangerousShipment::getValue`

Comment: By the way, by convention the enum instance names should be all uppercase as constants.  So `DANGER` and `NORMAL`. And the enum class name should have initial letter uppercase, `Danger`, not `danger`. Lastly, you might consider a more descriptive  enum name such as `DangerLevel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a getter for the value:

```
public enum DangerShipment {
    // Code from the OP omitted for brevity

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And use it when constructing the list:

```
List<String> dangerlist = Stream.of(DangerousShipment.values())
                                .map(DangerousShipment::getValue)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Complete Code:

```
    public enum danger {

        Danger("DGR"), Normal("NOR");

        private danger(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        /**
         * The value.
         */
        private final String value;

        /**
         * @return the value
         */
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

List<String> dangerlist = Stream.of(danger.values())
                                .map(x -> x.getValue())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```